# sql syntax error with VERY basic command? why?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, rdbms

I am trying just create a table using MySql Workbench. Here's the sql command:

```
CREATE TABLE `bmxData`.`new_table` ();
```

yet I get this error while executing this :-

> Executing:
>
> CREATE TABLE `bmxData`.`new_table` ();
>
> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
>
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
>
> SQL Statement:
>
> CREATE TABLE `bmxData`.`new_table` ()

Any idea why? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add at least one column:

```
CREATE TABLE `bmxData`.`new_table`(col INT);
```

Some RDBMS allow to define table without explicit user column like PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tab();
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2df3c5364c79191356a5ebae22a3712e)**

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion in relational theory of the meaning of tables with zero columns. Also described as *relations of zero degree*.

Relational theory researcher C. J. Date refers to `TABLE_DUM` and `TABLE_DEE`. Both have no columns, but the difference is that `TABLE_DUM` has no columns and no rows, whereas `TABLE_DEE` has one row (even though that row has no columns).

See this excerpt from "Database in Depth: Relational Theory for Practitioners": https://flylib.com/books/en/2.214.1.38/1/

The following query will therefore return no rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_DUM CROSS JOIN MyTable;
```

Whereas this query will return the same rows and columns as `MyTable`:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_DEE CROSS JOIN MyTable;
```

So there's some precedent and significance for a table with no columns. You can think of it by analogy as the role of 0 and 1 in multiplication:

- 0 x any number is 0
- 1 x any number is the same number

HOWEVER, standard SQL doesn't allow it. SQL doesn't exactly implement all of the concept of relational theory faithfully. In this case, standard SQL defines a table as having at least one column. The designers of SQL decided that a table with no columns isn't so interesting as to justify support in the SQL language.

If PostgreSQL or some other implementation of SQL decides to allow a table with no columns, they are doing it as an extension to standard SQL.